# How to access data from one form and bring to another

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am trying to pull a label text into another form inside the same solution to use in an if statement. However, it seems as though it's not pulling the data from the field. I am trying to change the color of the label background based on the label text in form 1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

IN FORM 1:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1 view = new form();
    view.Show();
    view.label1 = label1.Text.ToString();
}
```

IN FORM 2:

```
public string label1 { get; set; }

public void Display()
{
    if (label1 == "1")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nWinnings.Length; i++)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.BackColor = Color.Red;
            ...
        }
     }
     else
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < nWinnings.Length; i++)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            ...
        }
      }
}
```

There is more to the label but the label is working fine minus the color change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
Label label = new Label();
```

You cannot create a *new* instance of your `Label`... it has absolutely no connection to the original `Label` instance in the first `Form`, and changing any property on it will not affect the original one either.

---

You'll need to pass a reference to the entire `Label`:

```
// Form 1

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1 view = new form();
    view.label1 = label1;
    view.Show();
}

// Form 2

public Label label1 { get; set; }

public void Display()
{
    if (label1.Text == "1")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nWinnings.Length; i++)
        {
            label1.BackColor = Color.Red;

            // ... etc, etc
```

---

I'd limit how much passing around of references to controls you do to other Forms. In my experience, code starts to get quite muddy when you do that too much.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Grant Winney. I tried this change and I'm getting a "NullReferenceException was unhandled".

Comment: At the if statement. I believe so, though I am pretty new to C# and could have missed something basic.

Comment: Ok. I will look through again and see if I can't find what I may have missed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If what I understood is correct, you have 2 forms. FORM1 & FORM2.
You have a label control LABEL1 in FORM1. You read this text and pass it to FORM2.

In FORM2, you have another label control LABEL2, whose background color you want to change.

You can declare a string variable in FORM2.
Add a new constructor to FORM2 to accept a string argument, and set this value to the string variable.
In FORM2 OnLoad, you can then check the value of your string variable and
then,
LABEL2.BackColor = whateverColor in the if-else loop.

something like this in FORM1

```
FORM2 newForm = new FORM2(LABEL1.Text);
newForm.Show();
```

and in FORM2

```
private label1String = String.Empty();

public FORM2(string arg)
{
    ...Default Initialization Code...
    label1String = arg;
}

private void ChangeLabel2Color()
{
    if(label1String == "1")
    {
        LABEL2.BackColor = whateverColorYouNeed;
    }
    else
    {
        ...WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO...
    }
}
```

I wrote the code directly, so there might be syntax errors.